# Regular expression for a dynamic URL in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am Pretty new to Jmeter and Regular expressions.
The below bold one characters changes every time a new link is generated for user. So I want to add a regular expression for the below.
Can some one help me in this?

> /SummitHealthIVV/Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=**+ettnTn2YqkmqZJBlj3UMa1UMQv8J4seVZco7UV8tiR0GaDccb3Xbqfdrx7FXSwwHSqyBTQ7kK4FeQXFvgtnpiWKJ7rLsM1UKzGAtnkQGfPBIjh2LjlN7JKny7hfX7nGG**

Comment: Well, and what variants have you already tried and were have you failed?

Comment: Hmmmm, Shouldn't this work ? `strQueryString=([\w\+]+)`

Comment: Hi Alies,To be more clear with my case the above url appears in PATH section in HTTP request and also under the Parameters. Honestly I have give a simply try for Regular Expression - /SummitHealthIVV/Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=(.+?)

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply and I tried this in Regex - /SummitHealthIVV/Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=([\w\+]+) and No luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/strQueryString\=([a-z0-9\+]{1,})/i
```

or

```
/strQueryString\=(\S{1,})/i
```

Comment: Raheel, I have given this a try and test is not succeeded. I don't where I have committed a mistake. I used this /SummitHealthIVV/Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=([a-z0-9\+]{1,})/i for Regex in Jmeter

Comment: You need to see how to enter the regex switch in jmeter as the current `"/i"` doesnt look correct. However, in other languages, this regex works fine and I have tested it.

Comment: Please paste the exact code line you have where you have this regex applied

Comment: This is the URL - /SummitHealthIVV/Common/ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=+ettnTn2YqkmqZJBlj3UMa1UMQv8J4seVZco7UV8tiR0GaDccb3Xbqfdrx7FXSwwHSqyBTQ7kK4FeQXFvgtnpiWKJ7rLsM1UKzGAtnkQGfPBIjh2LjlN7JKny7hfX7nGG

Comment: This is the exact code line - <form name="form1" method="post" action="ElectronicSignatureAcceptance.aspx?strQueryString=+AgTHzhdLQMYBxF((MFOi1Ax3%2fK2HO9vBWFmUrtZ0m3%2fwnyZ54aVXJnPfKkM%2f5CJUw4q8srHPBd6AC0uigbfRdxs(DpsV75uCl%2fXlPlQ1cgbEPOcba50(QiDQQ7Z2Hbr4" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">

Comment: No, I meant the code which checks this string against the regex (i.e. from the processing code on or after submit)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28893/discussion-between-user2168410-and-raheel-hasan)